# Dropdown not working in ipa release. working in Android , also on the simulator in iOS

Tags: ios, flutter, dart, dropdownbutton

In the attached screenshot, there is a city filed below Address2, which is being replaced by a gray area. This is working in Android properly, also on the simulator in iOS, but not in IPA release app.

[image]

Comment: What is the expected screenshot for that area? How does it look in the simulator?